# Buying stocks probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

So I have this question and can't get the final result -
If a stock goes up daily by $X$ dollars, and the distribution is $X∼U(−0.15,0.37)$. The cost of a stock today is one dollar and I want to buy $200$ stocks.

What is the probability that in $75$ days the value of all stocks in my hand ($200$ stocks) will not go above $1800$ dollars?

I multiplied 200 by the uniform distribution commutative formula, with $X=1$.
and then I was not sure how to calculate the value of stock after $75$ days so I calculated it with CDF also, as $g(x)$, am I not in the right direction?

Comment: Have you thought about the *central limit theorem*?

Comment: General note:  it's not realistic  to imagine that your $200$ stocks move independently.  Of course you can make that assumption in order to get a math problem out of it, but such an assumption really needs to be stated explicitly.

Comment: @lulu You can assume that the stocks move in the same way, which means that the covariance is 1.

Comment: Are you able to compute the distribution of stock values after two days?  What prevents you applying the same method repeatedly to get the distribution after 75 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to evaluate the expected value. $\mathbb E(X)=\frac{0.37+(-0.15)}{2}=0.11$. And the variance is $Var(X)=\frac{(0.37-(-0.15))^2}{12}=\frac{169}{7500}\approx 0.0225333$ If you buy 200 stocks the corresponding values for the changes are

$\mathbb E(200X)=200\cdot \frac{0.37+(-0.15)}{2}=22$ and  $Var(200X)=\frac{2704}{3}\approx 901.3333$

Now you can apply the *central limit theorem* in order  to calculate that in $75$ days the value of all will not go above 1800 dollars. You have to assume that the change of the stocks at day $t$ does not affect the change in $t+1$ (much).